# Desperately need Help with a task for a test in Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, module, product-list, product-sorting, custom-button

So guys, I'm doing this task for something very important to me but now I'm completely stuck.

I need to fulfill this task:

> Create a module to output a nice list of the products that have a value in the position field. The list should be sorted according to the value in the position field, lowest number shows first. The list should contain the product name and a picture of the product. When you click on the product name or picture you should get to the product detail view. Then Add a button somewhere on the page that reverses the sort order when you click it.

So, to sum up, I have 5 products with a custom attribute(this is a textfield and the code is position_new), 3 of the products have values in this field(1,2,3) and 2 don't. I need to display only the products which have value in this field, then sort the products by the values in this field(position_new).

So far I've managed to create a ***similiar*** module that displays the products that contain value in the custom attribute, in this case color, but I can't sort the list of products and create the button. It's been two days only researching this but so far I found nothing helpful and I'm running against time.

This is my code, and if someone can help me with this will have my forever gratitude and will completely change my life, so please please anyone.

app/etc/modules/Atwix_Cmsattr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Cmsattr>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Atwix_Cmsattr>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Cmsattr>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Atwix_Cmsattr>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <atwix_cmsattr>
                <class>Atwix_Cmsattr_Block</class>
            </atwix_cmsattr>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <atwix_cmsattr>
                <class>Atwix_Cmsattr_Model</class>
            </atwix_cmsattr>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/Block/List.php

```
<?php
class Atwix_Cmsattr_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_itemCollection = null;

    public function getItems()
    {
        $color = $this->getColor();
        if (!$color)
            return false;
        if (is_null($this->itemCollection)) {
            $this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('atwix_cmsattr/products')->getItemsCollection($color);
        }

        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/Model/Products.php

```
<?php
class Atwix_Cmsattr_Model_Products extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
    public function getItemsCollection($valueId)
    {   
        $collection = $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => $valueId));
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);    
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

app/desing/frontend/rwd/default/template/atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml

```
<?php $_items = $this->getItems() ?>
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Red Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="category-products">
        <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-3-col first last odd">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item last">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info" style="padding-bottom: 88px; min-height: 151px;">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current result output
[image: Current result output]

Comment: Maybe checkout http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/18/magento-collection-paging/ see if you can integrate using their examples ...

Comment: Ive used the link above many times to achieve somewhat same requirements..

Comment: public function getAvailableOrders(){
        return array('created_time'=> 'Created Time','update_time'=>'Updated Time','collection_id'=>'ID');
    }
    public function getSortBy(){
        return 'collection_id';
    }

Comment: Welcome @Natsu! Can you show us how you created the custom attribute? Did you created it over the magento backend or with code?

I think I see one mistake, maybe change `Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);` to `$collection = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);`

Comment: @BENN1TH  thank you for the suggestion, I'll try now and post here a feedback

Comment: @Black Hi, yes I created over the backend by Catalog>Manage Attribute>....

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the resulting output?

Comment: @Black I didn't know how to add an image in the comments so I updated the post.

Comment: @Natsu, Question 1. You write `$color = $this->getColor();` but getColor() is not defined?? Did you provide all code?!

Comment: @Natsu, Question 2: On what criteria would you like to sort? Name?

Comment: @Black, Yes that's all the code and it's working to only display the products with the specific color, in this case red, but I can't get a custom toolbar working to sort the product.

Comment: @Black, This code is some I got it after researching for hours and modifying to work for my case, but it's not even what a really need. What I really need is to only display the products that contain a value in the attribute position_new that I've created through Magento backend, after that it needs to display a toolbar with only 1 button to change the sorting and that's it. Rn I'm trying to change this code to fit this reality, but I'm having difficulty.

Comment: But what are you trying to sort? The product names? The price?

Comment: @Black, in the case of the example, is the product color. But what I actually need is to sort the product position(this is an attribute that I've created on the backend with the code "position_new")

Comment: And of what type is "position_new" ? Is it an integer? Can you please update your question with position_new so we understand the problem?

Comment: @Black, Ok I will post the tasks that I have to complete. just a sec please

Comment: @Black, please see if you can understand now. If you like and is not a problem for you we can move this discussion to a chant somehow.

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem.

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml**:

You will need to add two new buttons so you can order ascending and descending.

These buttons are calling javascript functions on click which are sorting according to position_new.

```
<?php $_items = $this->getItems(); ?>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Red Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="category-products">
        <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-3-col first last odd">
        <?php $count = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>

            <li class="item <?php if(count($_items) == $count) { echo " last"; } ?>">

                <input hidden type="number" value="<?php echo $_item->getData('position_new') ?>" />

                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" 
                   title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" 
                   class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" 
                         alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info" style="padding-bottom: 88px; min-height: 151px;">
                    <h2 class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php $count++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="sort('asc')">Sort Asc</button>
<button class="button" onclick="sort('desc')">Sort Desc</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function sort(sortOrder)
    {
        var list = jQuery(".category-products").children().closest("ul");

        sortUsingNestedValue(list, "li", "input", sortOrder);
    }

    function sortUsingNestedValue(parent, childSelector, keySelector, sortOrder) 
    {
        var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
            var vA = jQuery(keySelector, a).val();
            var vB = jQuery(keySelector, b).val();

            if (sortOrder == "asc") {
                return ((vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0);
            } else if (sortOrder == "desc") {
                return ((vA > vB) ? -1 : (vA < vB) ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
        parent.append(items);
    }

</script>
```

> **Tipp**: You can get the attribute value in two ways.
>
> 1. `$_item->getData('position_new');`
> 2. `$_item->getPositionNew();`

---

I also had to change your Model.

**app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/Model/Products.php**

```
<?php
class Atwix_Cmsattr_Model_Products extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
    public function getItemsCollection()
    {   
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('position_new', array('notnull' => true));

        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

...and your Block Class.

**app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/Block/List.php**

```
<?php
class Atwix_Cmsattr_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_itemCollection = null;

    public function getItems()
    {        
        if (is_null($this->_itemCollection)) {
            $this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('atwix_cmsattr/products')->getItemsCollection("position_new");
        }

        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
}
```

[image]

You can remove the attribute `hidden` in `<input hidden type="number" value="<?php echo $_item->getData('position_new') ?>" />` at `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml` and play with the values to see that it works.

[image]

**Hint**: I changed the values in the picture above.

**Final Tip**: You should always take time when writing your questions. Always include all necessary informations in your post. You started very well and provided all needed code. But then you started to bring in `position_new` which we helpers would need to know from start.

Comment: Hey man, I completely understood your code and it seems that's it, thank you very much for it. For now I'm just not getting any results but I think it's something in the page that I've created through backned. I will look the code and soon as I get it working fine, I'll let you know. But thank so far for the patience and the help

Comment: No problem :) Maybe you have to clear your cache. Also check your logfiles in `var/logs`

Comment: @Natsu, it was extremly rude from you to delete your question after I helped you half a day to solve your problem. Why did you deleted it? So that your boss can't see that I helped you solving your test for you? I will never help you again, thats for sure.