# Invalid Blocktype

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, extensions, cms

I try to [help a user on magento.stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242363/desperately-need-help-with-a-task-for-a-test-in-magento-1-9-3?noredirect=1#comment338529_242363). So I created his extension and created a new CMS site with the following content:

```
{{block type="atwix/cmsattr" template="atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml"}}
```

I also allowed the block in the backend at (System -> Permissions -> Blocks).

But if I call the site, then there is no output from the block.

**app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Cmsattr>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Atwix_Cmsattr>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <atwix_cmsattr>
                <class>Atwix_Cmsattr_Block</class>
            </atwix_cmsattr>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <atwix_cmsattr>
                <class>Atwix_Cmsattr_Model</class>
            </atwix_cmsattr>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Atwix/Cmsattr/Block/List.php**

```
<?php
class Atwix_Cmsattr_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_itemCollection = null;

    public function getItems()
    {
        $color = $this->getColor();
        if (!$color)
            return false;
        if (is_null($this->itemCollection)) {
            $this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('atwix_cmsattr/products')->getItemsCollection($color);
        }

        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
}
```

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml**

I replaced his template content with "hello world"

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Verify the module is enabled in `app/etc/modules` and in `System/Configuration/Advanced`
2. You did the permissions change
3. `{{block type="atwix_cmsattr/list" template="atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml"}}`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had to use

```
{{block type="atwix_cmsattr/list" template="atwix/cmsattr/list.phtml"}}
```